How do I restrict the allow keys of an object with Typescript generics?
I want to only allow one type of object as function parameter. Object keys must start with $, only contain alphabetical characters, and its values must be of type Test. Under "example 1" below, I only managed to restrict to keys of type string. I found a DFA generator online, which manages to check compile time if a string starts with $ ("example 2"). How do I combine these two, so an object's keys are enforced to start with $? Note the variables validKey and invalidKey at the bottom under "example 3".
// example 1

interface Test {
  testProperty: string;
}

interface TestObject {
  [key: string]: Test;
}

const testObject: TestObject = {
  $prop1: {testProperty: 'test'},
  $prop2: {testProperty: 'test2'},
};

// example 2

type Head<StrT extends string> = StrT extends `${infer HeadT}${string}` ? HeadT : never;

type Tail<StrT extends string> = StrT extends `${string}${infer TailT}` ? TailT : never;

interface Dfa {
  startState: string;
  acceptStates: string;
  transitions: Record<string, Record<string, string>>;
}
type AcceptsImpl<DfaT extends Dfa, StateT extends string, InputT extends string> = InputT extends ''
  ? StateT extends DfaT['acceptStates']
    ? true
    : false
  : AcceptsImpl<DfaT, DfaT['transitions'][StateT][Head<InputT>], Tail<InputT>>;

type Accepts<DfaT extends Dfa, InputT extends string> = AcceptsImpl<
  DfaT,
  DfaT['startState'],
  InputT
>;

interface MyDfa {
  startState: '0';
  acceptStates: '1';
  transitions: {
    '0': Record<'$', '1'> & Record<string, 'fail'>;
    '1': Record<
      | 'A'
      | 'B'
      | 'C'
      | 'D'
      | 'E'
      | 'F'
      | 'G'
      | 'H'
      | 'I'
      | 'J'
      | 'K'
      | 'L'
      | 'M'
      | 'N'
      | 'O'
      | 'P'
      | 'Q'
      | 'R'
      | 'S'
      | 'T'
      | 'U'
      | 'V'
      | 'W'
      | 'X'
      | 'Y'
      | 'Z'
      | 'a'
      | 'b'
      | 'c'
      | 'd'
      | 'e'
      | 'f'
      | 'g'
      | 'h'
      | 'i'
      | 'j'
      | 'k'
      | 'l'
      | 'm'
      | 'n'
      | 'o'
      | 'p'
      | 'q'
      | 'r'
      | 's'
      | 't'
      | 'u'
      | 'v'
      | 'w'
      | 'x'
      | 'y'
      | 'z',
      '1'
    > &
      Record<string, 'fail'>;
    fail: Record<string, 'fail'>;
  };
}

type ValidObjectKey<T extends string> = Accepts<MyDfa, T>;

// example 3

const checkValidObjectKey = <T extends string>(key: T) => {
  return key as ValidObjectKey<T>;
};

const validKey = checkValidObjectKey('$valid'); // validKey is of type "true"
const invalidKey = checkValidObjectKey('invalid'); // invalidKey is of type "false"



This code takes up a lot of vertical space. Could you [edit] so that it fits on a single screen at once? That will help others analyze it without having to scroll around.

(see prev comment).  That dfa is very complex and apparently doesn't allow keys with numbers in them so $prop1 is bad? ‍♂️ Well, assuming we must use that dfa instead of a more straightforward type, you can combine them as shown in this playground link. Note that there is no specific type that works the way you want TestObject to work, so you need a generic type and a helper function. If that fully addresses the question I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Try:
type Test = {
  testProperty: string;
}

type TestObject = Record<`$${string}`, Test>;

const config: TestObject = {
  $a: { testProperty: 'a' },
  $b: { testProperty: 'a' },
};

See demo
